# No PID file error deploying with sunspot with Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, sunspot-solr

I am trying to deploy Sunspot Solr with Capistrano. I have been setting this up based on this gist: https://gist.github.com/doitian/1795439.

**deploy.rb**

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end

  desc "Migrate Database"
  task :migrate_db do
    run "cd #{current_path} && rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production"
    run "touch #{current_path}/tmp/restart.txt"
  end

  desc "Create Solr Directory"
  task :setup_solr_data_dir do
    run "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/solr/data"
  end
end

namespace :solr do
  desc "start solr"
  task :start, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec sunspot-solr start --port=8983 --data-directory=#{shared_path}/solr/data --pid-dir=#{shared_path}/pids"
  end
  desc "stop solr"
  task :stop, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec sunspot-solr stop --port=8983 --data-directory=#{shared_path}/solr/data --pid-dir=#{shared_path}/pids"
  end
  desc "reindex the whole database"
  task :reindex, :roles => :app do
    stop
    run "rm -rf #{shared_path}/solr/data"
    start
    run "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:reindex"
  end
end

after "deploy", "deploy:cleanup", "deploy:migrate_db", 'deploy:setup_solr_data_dir', 'solr:stop', 'solr:reindex', 'solr:start'
```

I have set the IP for my internal server which is hosting my production app in sunspot.yml:

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: [My Server IP]
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    # read_timeout: 2
    # open_timeout: 0.5
```

When I try to run **cap deploy**, I get the following error:

```
* 2013-04-24 08:28:04 executing `solr:stop'
  * executing "cd /home/username/apps/appname/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sunspot-solr stop --port=8983 --data-directory=/home/username/apps/appname/shared/solr/data --pid-dir=/home/datacomm/apps/appname/shared/pids"
    servers: ["0.0.0.0"]
    [0.0.0.0] executing command
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] java version "1.7.0_15"
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] 
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.7) (7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] 
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] 
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] **No PID file at /home/username/apps/appname/shared/pids/sunspot-solr.pid**
 ** [out :: 0.0.0.0] 
    command finished in 990ms
failed: "rvm_path=$HOME/.rvm/ $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm-shell '1.9.3' -c 'cd /home/username/apps/appname/current && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sunspot-solr stop --port=8983 --data-directory=/home/username/apps/appname/shared/solr/data --pid-dir=/home/username/apps/appname/shared/pids'" on 0.0.0.0
```

What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `run` executes the command provided in the `solr:stop` task, it looks like you're not yet running solr, so their is no pid file for solr present. You're trying to stop a process that doesn't exist.

A Capistrano task is going to throw an exception if the code returned from `run` is an error code. You can fix this by forcing that command to never return an error.

Make that `run` command look like this

```
run("YOUR COMMAND HERE > /dev/null 2>&1 || true")
```

Now if you call `solr:stop` when solr isn't running, `true` will return, letting Capistrano continue on.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Deefour's solution, a more verbose approach could be wrap the 'run' command in a 'begin/rescue' statement:

```
....
desc "start solr"
task :start, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
  begin
    run "cd #{current_path} && RAILS_ENV=#{rails_env} bundle exec sunspot-solr start --port=8983 --data-directory=#{shared_path}/solr/data --pid-dir=#{shared_path}/pids"
  rescue Exception => error
    puts "***Unable to start Solr with error: #{error}."
    puts "***Continuing anyway.***"
  end
end
...
```